# R concatenating a table into a string

Tags: r, string

I have a dataframe

```
A              |       B
A_Long_String  |       7.1123
Another_String |       1234124
```

and I need to change it into a long string to feed into sql proc.
So the format needs to be

```
' "A_Long_String": "7.1123" \n "Another_String": "1234124" \n '
```

etc etc

What is the best way of doing this. Do I just have to loop?
The dataframe can be upwards of 100,000 rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, dQuote)
paste(do.call(paste, c(df1, sep=": ")), '\n', collapse=' ')
#[1] "“A_Long_String”: “7.1123” \n “Another_String”: “1234124” \n"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("A_Long_String", "Another_String"),
B = c(7.1123, 
1234124)), .Names = c("A", "B"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```